# DA40 fuselage static ports / G1000 not in AFM

Tags: diamond-da40

I’m a flight instructor who just switched from instructing in 172’s to flying the Diamond DA40 and am confused about a few things. Our DA40 has two static ports, one on either side of the fuselage. This doesn’t make sense to me because the AFM in the airplane says the static ports are on the left wing along with the pitot probe. I haven’t been able to find anything online about these static ports, and I’ve only seen one DA40 AFM.

My second confusion is, the airplane is equipped with a G1000; however, the AFM in the airplane doesn’t say anything about the G1000, there is only a cockpit reference guide for it. Would this indicate an upgrade from original avionics? Would it be in the maintenance records? (Mx records was my next stop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by further reading the AFM. On DA40's with an auto pilot installed, optional static ports may be added to the fuselage.

Answer (score 1):

My guess if you have an older airplane with a separate autopilot that is not integrated with the G1000.

If you have an autopilot with a separate static system, such as the KAP-140, there will be additional static ports. They should be noted in the AFM, but in the supplement section referring to the KAP-140 autopilot.

In contrast an airplane with a G1000 integrated autopilot (GFC-700) the autopilot will share airdata with the G1000, so it will not have an extra static port, but rather just a wire to get airdata from the GIA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing my flight training on DA40NG. Are you thinking about alternate static valve? It's correct that there is static port on left and right side of fusalge more like rear and pitot tube on left wing, also stall warning port on left wing leading edge. About G1000 shouldn't explain alot on AFM but you should read more on G1000 manual. I used to watch a video on youtube an hour long explained about G1000 all techincal stuff and more.